# How to install Scrapy in linux Machine

Tags: python, linux, web-scraping, scrapy

I am already install the python2.7 in my machine. Then i tried to install scrapy by using following commands but its throwing some exceptions.

```
root@boss[elcot]#pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg
Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading Twisted-13.2.0.tar.bz2 (2.7MB): 2.7MB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 274, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1173, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1320, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir, self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 587, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 543, in untar_file
    tar = tarfile.open(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1678, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1744, in bz2open
    raise CompressionError("bz2 module is not available")
CompressionError: bz2 module is not available

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How to solve this.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to install `pip` in your `python2.7` installation:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

If you end up with multiple `pip` commands, you can call the one from `python2.7` like this

```
python2.7 -m pip install scrapy
```

Comment: elcot@boss:~$ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
--2014-02-02 20:14:58--  https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
Resolving raw.github.com... 103.245.222.133
Connecting to raw.github.com|103.245.222.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1563245 (1.5M) [text/plain]
Saving to: “get-pip.py”

100%[======================================>] 1,563,245   1.87K/s 
2014-02-02 20:28:07 (1.95 KB/s) - “get-pip.py” saved
 
           elcot@boss:~$ python2.7 -m pip install scrapy
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip

Comment: You forgot to run: `python2.7 get-pip.py`

Answer (score 1):

Try to install by easy install.

easy_install scrapy.

This will be helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a symlink `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`.